# Normal curve for normal distribution

Tags: regression, normal-distribution

I'm reading Linear Regression and correlation by Scott Hartshorn. There is Regression  example for a television show Modern Family. We calculated equation for a regression line to predict number of viewers of that show. Then there is the example predicting errors between predicted number of viewers and actual value.
So we have

```
____________________________________________________________________________
|Normalized   |      Predicted normalized               |   Regression error |
|viewers (Nv) |  viewers with our Regression line(PNv)  |      (PNv - Nv)    |
|____________________________________________________________________________|
|1            |              0.915                      |        -0.085      |
|0.79         |              0.907                      |         0.114      |
|...          |              ...                        |         ...        |
|_____________|_________________________________________|____________________|
```

We made a histogram of the regression errors.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Then the author drew normal curve(it is on the histogram). And I don't understand the formula is being used to draw that curve.

We have standard deviation of Regression errors = 0.074
There is table with data for provided histogram above.

```
_______________________________________________________________________________
Histogram bin index   |    Histogram bins |          Normal curve              |
______________________|___________________|____________________________________|
       1              |         -0.2      |      =NORM.S.DIST(-0.2/0.074, 0)*  |
                      |                   |   Number_of_episodes*(0.02/0.074)=0.458  |
______________________|___________________|____________________________________|
       2              |         -0.18     |      =NORM.S.DIST(-0.18/0.074, 0)* |
                      |                   |   Number_of_episodes*(0.02/0.074)=0.9194  |
       ...            |         ...       |            ...                     |
______________________|___________________|____________________________________|
```

Per my understanding normal curve consists of product of 3 parts:

1. NORM.S.DIST(-0.2/0.074, 0) That excel function is used to calculate probability density function value for standard distribution. -0.2/0.074 - Z score and 0 - is just a marker that we need to use density.

2.Number_of_episodes as far as I understand it is size of sample. It is sum of values from y axis on the histogram above.

3.(0.02/0.074) not sure what it is. Based on the table and graph above, 0.02 is distance between bins on histogram. 0.074 is standard deviation.

Can you please explain what is the formula being used by author to calculate normal curve? I though that NORM.S.DIST(-0.2/0.074, 0) is enough.

I'm kind of newbie in statistic and probability, sorry if I missed some data to be shown. I will edit the message and add it.

Answer (score 1):

A normal distribution is completely characterized by its mean $\mu$ and its standard deviation $\sigma$ (equivalently, its variance $\sigma^2.$) Once you compute the mean (I assume you know how to compute that) and the (sample) standard deviation:
$$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-\overline{y})^2},$$
then the formula for a normal distribution is
$$f(y)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\exp\left[-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right].$$
However, as whuber pointed out in his comment, the histogram shown is not that of a distribution, since the area underneath it is clearly greater than $1.$ To get an approximate height for the curve, you can simply multiply the formula above by the sum of all the values (an approximation to the area under the curve) times the horizontal differential:
$$\tilde{f}(y)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\exp\left[-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]\times\Delta x\times\sum_{i=1}^ny_i.$$

This is my guess for how the author made the normal curve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to play with that formula. But It doesn't work for me. In fact the probability density function is used in Excel function NORM.S.DIST with mean  equal 0 and standard deviation equal to 1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "But it doesn't work for me." Can you clarify?

Comment: The curve is adjusted to reflect (a) a particular standard deviation and (b) normalization to a total count rather than a unit probability.  A full explanation should include both these points.

Comment: @Adrian I tried to calculate "Normal curve" values in the table with f(x)=(1/σ√2π)*exp(-((x-μ)^2)/2σ^2) So I used standard deviation -  0.074(standard deviation of errors); x - is value from x axis on histogram(e.g. 0.2); μ - zero. I got 0.137955 what is different of author's value(I updated my message)

Comment: Agree with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma\approx 0.074.$ See the edit for "de-normalizing", so-to-speak, as whuber pointed out.

Comment: @Adrian Keister Sum of regression errors gives me 0. Looks like your guess doesn't work

Comment: You're not doing what I recommended: you need to sum the $y$ values - the number of episodes with each error amount. There's NO WAY that's $0.$ I would estimate it should be around $194.$ Actually, you are also going to have to multiply that $194$ by the horizontal width of each bin - or $0.02.$ Essentially, you are integrating by Riemann sums.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I updated my first message. I added tables with author's calculations(column Normal curve) and frequencies for bins. I tried to calculate the first cell value for Normal curve as you suggested f(x)=(1/(0.074*((2*PI())^(1/2))))*EXP(-(1/0.074)^2) = z => z * 0.02 * 166 = 4.9237063431307E+081

Comment: @AdrianKeister as far as I understand authors doesn't want to integrate it at that stage. He's using probability DENSITY function not cumulative. Sum of their results is more than 1

Comment: Check your calculations. There's something seriously wrong. You shouldn't get anything even close to $10^{81}.$ I get an area of exactly $3.32.$